# How to hide the "filmstrip" in DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the "network" tab of DevTools, a film strip has appeared below the filter, and above the list of files:

[image]

It hides the list of files unless the DevTools window is several hundred pixels high, so now I spend a lot of time resizing my browser window trying to see the list of files. How do I hide it?

I've been hunting through the options, but can't find any option to disable or hide the filmstrip.

Comment: If you mean the screenshots, click the camera icon (3rd in the toolbar) to toggle them.

Comment: Thank you! Screenshots gone :) I still see the timing bar - any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: The mini-waterfall under the screenshots? Click the button before "Group by frame".

Comment: Thank you so much! Feel free to submit as an answer!

Answer (score 5):

Now you can do this:

1. Select "Network Settings" (see figure)
2. Uncheck "Show overview"
3. Touch again "Network Settings" and ready

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update 2024 since Google keeps changing things for fun,

Now it is Network > Settings (Cog icon) > Overview

[image]